# I have to print frequency each alphabet in a string

Tags: java

In the following code,if i use 90 to 122,program doesnt work but if i use 65 to 92,it works even though the characters are UpperCase.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class rep
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        s=s.toUpperCase();
        char b;
        int i,a,c;
        a=s.length();
        for(i=90;i<=122;i++){
            c=0;
            for(int j=0;j<a;j++){
                if((char)i==s.charAt(j)){
                    c+=1;
                }
            }
            if(c>0)
            System.out.println((char)i+"\t\t\t" +c);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does your posted code look properly formatted to you? It doesn't to us, making it hard to read and understand, and so you'll want to fix this first and foremost. The easier it is for us to understand your code and your problem, the better the answers we can give.

Comment: Please elaborate the program 'doesn't work'.

Comment: Upper case letters are from 64-90, lower case are from 97-122.

Comment: Ok,ASCII from 90 is for UpperCase letters and from 65 is for lowercase. In my program,I am finding the frequency of alphabets in String,which has to be in UpperCase. So,if String is in UpperCase then why do i have to use 65.Also,on using 90,it just doesnt print anything..

Comment: Take a look at an [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters). You seem to have mistaken the code ranges for lower and upper case.

Answer (score 0):

Well 90-122 are lower case letters (97-122), while 65-92 are upper case letters. You have in your code this line: s=s.toUpperCase(); which converts whole String to upper case. That's why it isn't detecting lower case letters.

BTW. Java convention says to name your class with first letter capital.

Comment: My bad on the 97 mistake.....If I use 97 to 122,nothing gets printed but if i use 65 to 92,program runs wondrfully

Comment: You seem to have made the same mistake as the OP. 65-90 are *uppercase*, 97-122 are *lowercase*.

Comment: Yeah my mistake, I was thinking one thing and writing another. The post has been edited.